# Program in C to sum each digit in an integer

Tags: c, algorithm

```
int main(){
    int x;
    int sum;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    do{

        sum += (x%10);
        x=(x/10);

        if((x/10)==0){
            sum += x;
        }
    }
    while((x/10)!=0);

    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Hey, I'm trying to get this to add up each digit within the entered integer, but the code I'm using keeps returning the wrong output. Would someone please help me fix my equation/code, because I'm not sure why the output is incorrect.

Comment: post the input along with the output you get.

Comment: It's impossible to guess what you want from code alone, especially wrong code.

Comment: If you're a Dr. Who fan, check out this post on calculating Happy Primes.  http://forums.devshed.com/programming/661361-finding-happy-primes-post2381507.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your code

```
int sum;
```

is not initialized. use something like

```
int sum = 0;
```

Note: local variables are not automatically initialized [to `0` or anything], without explicit initialization their contents will be garbage. Thereby, using `sum += (x%10);` will lead to *read before-write* scenario, producing wrong result.

Comment: Tyvm, to you and everyone who answered. I'm new to C and the person teaching it to me hasn't been very clear on a lot of things.. And I learned debugger in Linux, so I'm not really sure how to use it in this IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small math problem:

> Somebody gave you ten apples, then someone else gave you two more. How many apples do you have?

The right answer is that this question is impossible to answer, because nobody told you how many apples you had at the beginning.

Your program suffers from the same problem: you failed to initialize `sum` before starting to add to it, so it has initial "garbage" value.

Changing the declaration to

```
int sum = 0;
```

will fix the problem.

Comment: Nice tips for asking good questions

Comment: Your example was helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable `sum` -

```
int sum = 0;
```

If you don't initialize your variable in `C`   and some other language then the a garbage/random value is assigned to it when it is used in expression for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

**Late Answer**

Since you've already found the problem with your code, I would like to provide a more concise alternative:

```
int x;
int sum = 0
int digit;

printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

while (x > 0) {
    digit = x % 10;
    sum += digit;
    x /= 10;
}
printf("%d", sum);
```

`x % 10` extracts the last digit of the number, and then `x /= 10` truncates the integer by removing the last digit.